# Time into duration/Session using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 1 pandas data-frame with date and time. I want to add 1 more column called session, with values morning afternoon, evening, night.

```
   Time
   2016-07-10 01:18:00
   2016-07-10 11:21:00
   2016-07-10 17:29:00
   2016-07-10 21:43:00
```

I want output like

```
   Time                     Session
   2016-07-10 01:18:00      Night
   2016-07-10 11:21:00      Morning
   2016-07-10 17:29:00      Afternoon
   2016-07-10 21:43:00      Evening
```

How to do this ?

I tried this by defining breaks

```
00:00 - 06:00 Night
06:00 - 12:00 Morning
12:00 - 18:00 Afternoon
18:00 -23:59 Evening


df.Time[(df.Time.dt.hour < 6) | (df.Time.dt.hour > 0) | (df.Time.dt.minute < 59) | (df.Time.dt.minute > 0)] = "Night"
```

But its not working properly. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your 2016-07-10 05:26:00  how is that afternoon and not morning?  There is no AM PM designation nor 24 hour clock.  Is it ordered based?

Comment: @Scott Boston - Corrected the question. Sorry. Now it will make sense

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `pd.cut` to create bins for your session labels.

```
df.assign(session=pd.cut(df.Time.dt.hour,[0,6,12,18,24],labels=['Night','Morning','Afternoon','Evening']))
```

Output:

```
                 Time    session
0 2016-07-10 01:18:00      Night
1 2016-07-10 11:21:00    Morning
2 2016-07-10 17:29:00  Afternoon
3 2016-07-10 21:43:00    Evening
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott Boston, Its working properly, But this is based on hours only, what if I want to 1 more condition of Minutes.

Comment: You could use `.dt.hours` and `.dt.mintutes` to create a calculation then create bins to match that calcuation.